# Cast Down to a Child Class

Tags: c#

Suppose I have 3 classes for Logging:

```
internal class ErrorLogDescriptor : InfoLogDescriptor
{
    public int ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RequestUrl { get; set; }
    public string Stack { get; set; }
}

internal class InfoLogDescriptor
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class LogDescriptor : ErrorLogDescriptor
{
}
```

When I am logging to `stdout` I first, using `JsonConvert`, deserialize into the `LogDescriptor` class by doing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogDescriptor>(data);`. Once I figure out the appropriate `LogLevel`, I would then like to cast down to one of the child classes depending on if the Level is of type `Info` or `Error`. Is it possible to do this by using a simple cast?

I have been attempting:

```
if (log.level == LogLevel.Info)
{
    log = (InfoLogDescriptor)log;
} 
else 
{
    log = (ErrorLogDescriptor)log;
}
```

But I have been seeing messages from Visual Studio saying that:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'InfoLogDescriptor' to 'LogDescriptor'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your variable is `log` of type `LogDescriptor` and you're trying to assign it an object of tpye `InfoLogDescriptor`, which you can't since it's a child class.

Do this instead:

```cs
if (log.level == LogLevel.Info)
{
    var newloggger = (InfoLogDescriptor)log;
} 
else 
{
    var newloggger = (ErrorLogDescriptor)log;
}
```